# How to turn off McAfee programmatically

Tags: windows-7, mcafee

I am running McAfee VirusScan Enterprise 8.7i on my Windows 7 machine.

I am writing this utility to configure McAfee. Now how do I turn off McAfee programmatically (using C++ or C#)?

The only ways I can do it right now are:

- Manually opening the McAfee Virusshield icon from the system tray and then selecting Exit.
- Run a command prompt under SYSTEM account (using System internals tool psexec) and then issue the command "sc stop McShield"

Comment: Why you don't execute the command "sc stop McShield" programmatically?

Comment: Buy their product to do mass-configurations: http://www.mcafee.com/us/enterprise/products/security_management_console/epolicy_orchestrator.html

Comment: Are you sure you're not writing a virus?

Comment: @hkda150 "sc stop McShield" will only work when the program that executes is running as SYSTEM account. Now the maximum elevation my program can get is "Administrator".

Comment: You can also force a reboot. Crude but effective ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the point of virus scanners is that they CANNOT be switched off by other software (at least not easily)

Comment: Definitely.  Antivirus software puts a lot of effort into preventing other programs from disabling it.

Comment: @thijs It is not possible even when i am running as admin. I need to run under SYSTEM account(something which my program can't afford) to accomplish that.

Comment: After several trials, it really seems that it is not possible to turn off McAfee 8.7i programatically;

Comment: this antivirus is slow for java developers, because it searches inside jar files for threats, which decreases the whole computer performance...and THAT's not a valid answer for the question!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the VShield icon in the system tray and choose Manage features and the VirusScan Enterprise
Double click on Access Protection to get to the properties
Un-check the option for "Prevent McAfee services from being stopped"
You should now be able to stop the McAfee services